# Django return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: CsExpert_user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I am working on a website, and whenever I want to create a new user, I am getting this error, and I don't know what to do next, it seems like tables for my models are not being created, in this case what can I do?

my models.py :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

my views.py:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "CsExpert/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "CsExpert/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "CsExpert/register.html")
```

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to migrate?

Comment: I have done migrations